# Unable to call member function pointer that is inside a struct

Tags: c++, c++11, x11, xlib

I've been racking my brain over getting the syntax right on declaring, defining and finally calling a member function pointer inside my program.

I'm writing a window manager with Xlib, and am trying to enable the user to define all key bindings in a vector of `Keybind`s. The `Keybind` struct contains more member variables, which I have left out here for the sake of brevity.

Here's what I've got so far.

`Keybind`, a struct containing a member variable, `func`, that points to a `MyClass` member function.

```
struct MyBind {
    MyBind(void (MyClass::*_func)(const XKeyEvent&))
    : func(_func) {}

    void (MyClass::*func)(const XKeyEvent&);
}
```

Declaration and populating of a `vector` that holds user-defined `Keybind`s.

```
// in my_class.hh
std::vector<MyBind*> my_binds_;

// in my_class.cc, constructor
my_binds_.push_back(new MyBind( &MyClass::do_this ));
my_binds_.push_back(new MyBind( &MyClass::do_that ));
```

At this point, everything compiles and runs.

Now, when I try to delegate work by iterating over the `my_binds_` vector, things go wrong. It is worth noting that I've left out error handling and other member variable accesses for clarity.

```
void
MyClass::handle_input(const XKeyEvent& e)
{
    for (const MyBind* my_bind: my_binds_) {
        (my_bind->*func)(e); // erroneous line
    }
}
```

This [should be the correct syntax](http://umich.edu/~eecs381/handouts/Pointers_to_memberfuncs.pdf), but it fails to compile, stating `error: ‘func’ was not declared in this scope` (`g++`, similar error from `clang++`).

This is weird to me, as replacing the erroneous line of code with `auto test = keybind->func;` *does* compile.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to handle user key bind definitions? Thanks!

Comment: I am sure you can duplicate this same error using a [mcve], some dummy classes,  and not need Xlib to duplicate the error.

Answer (score 1):

It would be best to use [std::function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and forget about raw member-function pointers altogether. They will only bring you pain :)

The problem with you code is that you only have a pointer to a method but no object. Your bind struct should also store an object pointer to call the method on:

```
struct MyBind {
    MyBind(MyClass *obj, void (MyClass::*_func)(const XKeyEvent&))
    : obj(obj), func(_func) {}

    MyClass *obj;
    void (MyClass::*func)(const XKeyEvent&);

    void operator()(const XKeyEvent& event) const
    {
        (obj->*func)(event);
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
void
MyClass::handle_input(const XKeyEvent& e)
{
    for (const MyBind* my_bind: my_binds_) {
        (*my_bind)();
    }
}
```

I've added a call operator to the bind struct for convenience. Note that the `->*` operator is applied to the **object the method belongs to**.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, rather a pointer to your answer or my so-question :)

You had to use

```
(this->*(my_bind->func))(e);
```

instead of:

```
(my_bind->*func)(e);
```

I have re-created your error msg and asked a question after many different attempts.

See this( pointer to your answer ;) ): [How to call pointer to member function, which has been saved in a vector of custom struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51904472/how-to-call-pointer-to-member-function-which-has-been-saved-in-a-vector-of-cust?noredirect=1#comment90760181_51904472)

`MyBind` holds the pointer to member function of some instance of `MyClass`. Therefore in order to call these function pointers, you need to explicitly tell using `this` keyword, for which instance of `MyClass` you want the `func` to be called.