# How to call pointer to member function, which has been saved in a vector of custom struct?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, pointer-to-member

My question is actually regarding [already asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51900083/unable-to-call-member-function-pointer-that-is-inside-a-struct). I have tried the [answer given by @r3mus n0x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51900083/unable-to-call-member-function-pointer-that-is-inside-a-struct/51900245#51900245) also have seen some SO questions which did not help me to get a clear idea about the above situation.

In the given post lacks MCVE, therefore I have tried a bit and came up with the following code and with the same error what @user10213044 mentioned in his/her post.

[**Error msg**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eaf7b203a8182302)

```
error C2065: 'm_func': undeclared identifier
```

My qestion:

**Q1**: Can we really store the pointer to some of the member functions of a class(like in the following example) into it's on private member(ex. vector array)? If so what is the reason for the above error msg?

**Q2**: I have also tried to write inside the for loop:

```
classFuncPtr fun = bindClassPtr->m_func; // compiles
fun(str); // error
```

gave me: [**Error msg**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1893f9568c7148bf)

```
error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in 'fun (...)', e.g. '(... ->* fun) (...)'
 fun(str); // error
```

which I could not understand. Can anybody tell me what went wrong in this case?

The second attempt was similar to the following case which we use for normal functions pointer case.

```
typedef void(*FuncPtr)(const std::string&);
FuncPtr Lambda = [](const std::string& str) { std::cout << str << std::endl; };
Lambda(std::string("Hellow World"));
```

Here is the code I tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class MyClass;          
typedef void (MyClass::*classFuncPtr)(const std::string&); // function ptr to MyClass::member functions

struct MyBind // bind struct
{
   classFuncPtr m_func;
   explicit MyBind(const classFuncPtr& func): m_func(std::move(func)) {}
};

class MyClass
{
    std::string m_var;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyBind>> my_binds_;
public:
   MyClass() // constructor 
   {
      my_binds_.emplace_back( std::make_unique<MyBind>( std::move(&MyClass::do_this) ));
      my_binds_.emplace_back( std::make_unique<MyBind>( std::move(&MyClass::do_that) ));
   }

   // two functions to bind
   void  do_this (const std::string& str) { std::cout << "From do this: " << str << std::endl;   }
   void  do_that (const std::string& str) { std::cout << "From do that: " << str << std::endl;   };

   void handle_input(const std::string& str)
   {

      for (const std::unique_ptr<MyBind>& bindClassPtr: my_binds_)
      {
          // how to print passed string str here??              (Q1)
          (bindClassPtr->*m_func)(str);

          /*
          classFuncPtr fun = bindClassPtr->m_func; // compiles   (Q2)
          fun(str); // error
          */
      }
   }
};
```

Comment: I guess this question is for educational / study purposes? Otherwise why would you consider your own handrolled bind functor, especially having just lambdas (and all kinda binding to their current stack frame scope)  at hand?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Why I get down vote even if I explained everything in detail. I wanted to learn from by doing, even if does not do any binding like `std::bind`.

Comment: You may inspect the code that is provided with the `std::bind()` template function. It's usually publicly inspectable as part of your compiler's c++ standard library implementation.

Comment: _"Why I get down vote ..."_ Because your question misses to provide a [MCVE] most probably. And also the syntax error description should be more or less self explanatory.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Sorry I could not understand the *syntax error description*. Thats why I asked for help. On the top of that I was trying to learn from the question, for which proper answer was not been there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178233/discussion-between-const-and--).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first attempt fails because there's no variable in scope named `m_func`.

Your second attempt fails because a pointer-to-member requires an object to be called on.

The correct syntax is:

```
classFuncPtr fun = bindClassPtr->m_func;
(this->*fun)(str);
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ece21f5c000b5f4)

The pointer contained in your `MyBind` objects isn't actually bound to anything.  It's a pointer to a member of `MyClass`, so you have to provide it an instance of `MyClass` to work on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer: but the syntax you provided also does not compile: https://wandbox.org/permlink/5rMQiptC8DRI5H83

Comment: also `bindClassPtr` has `m_func` inside.  Could you a working syntanx?

Comment: That did _compile_.  It failed to _link_ because you didn't provide a `main` function.

Comment: Sorry you are right: https://wandbox.org/permlink/eSx33x7uT9EFyCQK Thanks a lot

Comment: @MilesBudnek http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/

Comment: Combining your sythanx will also work for first qestion: `(this->*(bindClassPtr->m_func))(str);` Thanks alot. +1 for that ;)